# Making the JavaFX Tab "Selected" Style the same as the default "Focused" style

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx

I would like to apply the default "focus" style tab to my selected tab. Mainly I am trying to accomplish keeping the thin blue border around the tab regardless of whether or not the user is focused on the tab, but instead as long as it is the tab they have selected. I included an example of how it looks now when I am focused on something else and how I would like it to look when I am focused on something else.

```
/*Overrides the default and removes the 10px padding from the left most tab */
.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em; /* overridden as 5 2 0 0 */
}

.tab-header-background {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.tab-pane{
-fx-tab-min-width:90px;
}

.tab-pane .tab{
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0,0,0;
    -fx-background-color: #c6c6c6;
}

.tab-pane .tab:selected{
    -fx-background-color: #3c3c3c;
}

.tab .tab-label { 
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #828282;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.tab:selected .tab-label { 
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #96b946;
}
```

[image: Current Selected Tab Style]
[image: Desired Selected Tab Style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `modena.css` that selector looks like:

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    ...
}
```

Just use it without `:focused`:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-width: 1, 1;
    /*-fx-border-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-faint-focus-color;*/
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-insets: -4 -4 -6 -5, -2 -2 -5 -3;
    -fx-border-radius: 2, 1;
}
```

Comment: I had actually went there and toggled with that, I don't know why I didn't think of that. It worked perfectly, thanks!